# detecting when audio file is playing or ended

Tags: jquery, html, audio

I've already asked a question very similar to this but I can't get the suggested code to work.
the jquery is:

```
  jQuery("span").click(function (event) {
    var elementID = event.target.id;
    var oggVar = ("audio/"+elementID +".ogg");
    var audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
    audioElement.setAttribute("src", oggVar); 
    audioElement.play(); 
  });
```

This works OK, the problem is it works even tho another audio file is playing. I want to prevent this, so that an audio file does not run if another audio file is playing. Sorry to have to revisit this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered before, but let me take a shot at this. You're going to want to check to see if any audioclips are playing. I don't think there is a isPlaying sort of built in logic, but I know you can use the event listeners.

```
var audioIsPlaying = false;

jQuery("span").click(function (event) {
    if(audioIsPlaying != true) {
        var elementID = event.target.id;
        var oggVar = ("audio/"+elementID +".ogg");
        var audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
        audioElement.setAttribute("src", oggVar); 
        audioElement.play();
        audioIsPlaying = true;
        audioElement.addEventListener("ended", function() {
            audioIsPlaying = false;    
        });
    } else {
        //still playing
    }
});
```